# Is there much of a difference between backticks and quotation marks when printing something to the console in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example I could do :`` console.log(`Hello World`); `` and it would still run like `console.log('Hello World');`

The only difference I can see is I can do

```
let item1 = 'Food';
console.log(`I want ${item1}`);
```

and it would print I want food, whereas if I go

```
console.log('I want ${item1}');
```

using quotation marks it would print `"I want ${item1}"`

So is the only difference I can see is that I can call variables for one? And if so why do we use quotation marks in console logs?

Comment: Use whatever you like. Doesn't make much of a difference in the end.

Comment: When logging, it's usually better to log the value directly and not stringify it, so `console.log("I want", item1)` will come more handy in most situations

Comment: Yes, that is the only thing.

Comment: "*I can see is that I can call variables*" you can insert any valid expression but the result might not always be what you expect if the variable you use (or the result of the expression) is not a primitive type. For example, objects would be "stringified" to `[object Object]` and arrays would be joined so that `[1, 2, 3]` becomes `1,2,3`.

Comment: secan, when I did console.log(`1, 2, 3`) it still printed as 1, 2, 3

Comment: @Botany102 that is not an array. [Try it with an array](https://jsbin.com/vucihas/edit?js,console)

Comment: @secan what is the reason to use an array?

Comment: @secan also thank you for your patience, I'm really new.

Comment: @Botany102, maybe [this image](https://imgur.com/ZQZezNh) will help clarify what I meant. As for why you might use an array, they are a convenient way to group values in an *ordered* collection (if you put something in the first slot, it will always stay there unless you explicitly move it) so they come very handy, for example, when you have to perform the same operation on many different items (e.g. calculate the VAT of each product in you shopping cart).

Comment: @secan thank you, I didn't really understand the image but your explanation makes sense. I would upvote your comment but I don't have enough reputation to.

Comment: @Botany102, the image simply shows that if you try to log an array or an object using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (a string delimited by back ticks) in the console you will not see the actual value but its stringified version.

Comment: @secan Oh, okay. Thank you.